# Can't simplify expression with square roots of square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I'm very new to Mathematica, and I've been using it to evaluate some symbolic expressions in my research that are too complicated to do by hand. However, some of them don't simplify when it is obvious to me that it could be simplified further. The following is a simple example (compared to the much messier other expressions I have):

```
FullSimplify[Expand[Sqrt[1+2 Subscript[\[Gamma], Q]+Sqrt[1-4 Subsuperscript[\[Gamma], P, 2]+4 Subscript[\[Gamma], Q]]] Sqrt[(1-2 Subsuperscript[\[Gamma], P, 2]+2 Subscript[\[Gamma], Q]+Sqrt[1-4 Subsuperscript[\[Gamma], P, 2]+4 Subscript[\[Gamma], Q]])/(1+2 Subscript[\[Gamma], Q]+Sqrt[1-4 Subsuperscript[\[Gamma], P, 2]+4 Subscript[\[Gamma], Q]])] (1+4 Subscript[\[Gamma], Q]+Sqrt[1-4 Subsuperscript[\[Gamma], P, 2]+4 Subscript[\[Gamma], Q]])], 0<4 Subsuperscript[\[Gamma], P, 2]+4 Subscript[\[Gamma], Q]<1 \[And]Subscript[\[Gamma], P] \[Element] Reals \[And]Subscript[\[Gamma], Q] \[Element] Reals ]
```

(I also attached the screenshot for better readability)
[image]

So clearly the $$\sqrt{1+2\gamma_Q+\sqrt{1-4\gamma_P^2+4\gamma_Q}}$$ term can be cancelled out since I have a constraint that $\gamma_P, \gamma_Q$ are such that this term is strictly positive. I have tried both `Simplify`, `Expand` then `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, all with `Assumptions` option, as well as tighting the constraints on $\gamma_P, \gamma_Q$ so that they are not just real but in a smaller interval, so I'm not sure how to make this expression simplify even further. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: `PowerExpand` instead of `Expand` would do it.

Comment: I think I remember reading, but you should check this yourself to make certain that I am correct, that `FullSimplify` doesn't "denest radicals" and there is a library function somewhere that will enable Mathematica to do that in the cases where it is feasible to do. After that has been done then sometimes it is possible to further simplify some expressions. A Google Search for denest radical gives what looks like it might help. Or other searches might help. If that works for your problem then that may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Notice that `Superscript[x,2]=== x^2` is `False`. Do you mean for `Subsuperscript[\[Gamma], P, 2]` to mean `Subscript[\[Gamma],P]^2`? In any case, you should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining symbols or variables. Things like `Subscript[x, 1]` are not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning.  Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Syed points out:

```
FullSimplify[PowerExpand[YOUR EXPRESSION], your conditions]
```

$\left(\sqrt{-4 \gamma _P^2+4 \gamma _Q+1}+4 \gamma _Q+1\right) \sqrt{\sqrt{-4 \gamma
_P^2+4 \gamma _Q+1}-2 \gamma _P^2+2 \gamma _Q+1}$

Comment: That is not True for some variable combinations. `f[x, y] /. {x -> -5, y -> -4} // N`  yields `29.207`   and `FullSimplify[PowerExpand[f[x, y]], cond] /. {x -> -5, y -> -4} // N` yields `-29.207`

Comment: "your" conditions are the conditions the OP gives.

Comment: Then let me ask, why does FullSimplify not recognize this? `f[a, b] // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> cond] & // 
 FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> cond] &`should cancel the additions term `(-1)^Floor[(\[Pi] + Arg[1 + 2 b + Sqrt[1 - 4 a + 4 b]] - 
  Arg[1 - 2 a + 2 b + Sqrt[1 - 4 a + 4 b]])/(2 \[Pi])]`

Comment: Ok. Found the error. Didn't notice a typo in OP.  `Subsuperscript[\[Gamma], P, 2]` instead of `Subscript[\[Gamma], P]`

Comment: Nevertheless in this case not neccesary, but in general PowerExpand with conditions is needed.